# cocoapods - edit development pod's source file

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I have a question regarding cocoapods' development pod.

I find a source file in 'development pod' which contains a bug that I need to fix.
I know how to change the codes to fix it, but I am not quite sure how to fix/patch the file itself so that when I redo pod install later, it sustains the changes I made.

After some research, I figured out that I can fix/patch pod file by using https://github.com/jpsim/pod-diffs/blob/master/README.md

However, the file I like to fix resides in Development Pods.

According to https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/using-pod-lib-create,

> Development Pods are different from normal CocoaPods in that they are
> symlinked files, so making edits to them will change the original
> files, so you can work on your library from inside Xcode.

Does this mean I can safely make modifications in the file itself to fix the bug?
Sorry, I am not familiar with fixing Pod files. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this would work. When using a development pod, running `pod install` will not overwrite your changes with whatever is in the pod's repo, but instead will use the code as specified in the `:path` of your development pod.

When you do this, you should a) put the development pod under your own version control (usually in a fork of the original pod), and b) consider offering your fixes upstream via a pull request.

Comment: Thank you! I was not quite sure if the approach was correct and wanted to confirm. Also, thank you for the advices!